# Right Click Save as on dynamic href attribute

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage where I am using `selenium` to automate downloading of a file. I am able to navigate to the download page. All I have to do now is right click and click on `'save link as'` and click `"OK"`..

```
<tr>
    <td class="orionSummaryHeader">
        Export information:
    </td>
    <td class="orionSummaryColumn">                                                                                                                                                     
        <a href="/core/cache/qcW2AaqeD-s22J6yOlx958EJN7w=/Exported_Systems.csv"target="_blank">Exported_Systems.csv</a><br>                                                                                                                       
     </td>
 </tr>
```

I tried using `find_element_by_xpath()`, but still not able to click....
Help me out!

Comment: [How to download a file using Selenium's WebDriver?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to simulate right-click to save link. Just use below code:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Exported_Systems.csv').get_attribute('href')
```

If you want to use this link to download file, try:

```
import requests

with open("/path/to/file.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to automate the process of downloading file from the link, not just getting the link URL..

Comment: This seem to be a global issue, but as I understand the current local issue considering `All I have to do now is right click and click on 'save link as' and click "OK"` is just to get link