# Right click on an href and choose save link as in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to click on the Exported_Systems href and then choose "Save link as" in the drop down option. How do i go about this?

```html
<a href="/core/cache/0WDb_ukdMUOA7qoW9lt1cgnee0I=/Exported_Systems.csv" target="_blank">Exported_Systems.csv</a>
```

Comment: This seem to be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717222/right-click-save-as-on-dynamic-href-attribute/42717305#42717305 Do you need just to extract `URL` to `.csv` file?

Comment: the href is dynamic. so i cannot directly use the link to save the file

Comment: Why you cannot use it directly? This is still the same link... Share code you've already tried and failed to get desired result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might not be the perfect solution, but it will simulate the job.
You can use actionchains to open the right click menu.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[target="_blank"]')
actionChain = ActionChains(driver)
actionChain.context_click(elem).perform()
```

I have used "target" attribute to select the tag.
But now the problem is the access to that menu is out of the scope of selenium. So, here I used pyautogui to simulate 4 down arrow keys and the enter button press.(4 down arrow keys as "save link" option is 4th in every anchor tag)

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite(['down','down','down','down','enter'])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use profile in order to prevent the download dialogue:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')

driver= webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("yourWebSite")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href][text()[contains(., 'Exported_Systems')]]').click()
```